# Is there a way to reverse-beautify python code?

Tags: python

A specific unique task I have in mind requires me to read a text file (the text file only consists of python code) and store each line from the file in a list. However, there is one catch. I require each line to be **complete**. What I mean by complete is if a group of sequential lines can be in one line, without addition of any new characters and only the removal of '\n' characters, it should be in one line. Furthermore, it should not change the logic of the code at all. Here is some **non-exhaustive** examples what I mean by complete:

```py
# this is not complete
from rl.models import (
    Model1,
    Model2,
)

# this is complete
from rl.models import (    Model1,    Model2,)
```

```py
# this is not complete
print(1,
2)

# this is complete
print(1,2)
```

```py
# this is not complete
def func2(var1, 
    var2):

# this is complete
def func2(var1,     var2):
```

As you might have guessed it by now, I am not interested in the all of the unnecessary new lines in code which are usually done to improve readability. This is in a sense, uglyfying python code. If I run the uglyfied version of the python code, the same results is expected as the non-uglyfied version. I have tried to search for APIs which can do this but so far I have not come across any.

Comment: Your definition of "complete" is vague. `def func2(var1,    var2):` is just one part of the full `def` statement.

Comment: @chepner I have updated the post in response to your quesiton

Comment: If there are certain patterns in the code text, then maybe you could try using regex.

Comment: I would suggest looking at how [Black](https://github.com/psf/black) and other code formatters use the [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) to see how they approach this problem.

Comment: @dskrypa thanks for the suggestion to use ast's. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the complete statements using the ast module. Thanks @dskrypa.

```py
import ast

class CompleteLineVisitor(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def generic_visit(self, node):
        return(node)

if __name__=='__main__':
    with open('path/to/file') as f:
        tree = ast.parse(f.read())
        visitor = CompleteLineVisitor()
        mod_tree = visitor.visit(tree)
        print(ast.unparse(mod_tree))
```